# Confidence Interval for $\eta^2$

Tags: regression, confidence-interval, effect-size

Following my question [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/28199/wide-or-narrow-confidence-interval), I am also looking at the difference between males and females and I have conducted linear regression in a general linear model setup for this purpose.

My effect size for this part of the project is $\eta^2$ (which is 0.25).

$\eta^2$ is equivalent to $R^2$ (which is the appeal for me in this case).

I am wondering how do I calculate the confidence interval of $\eta^2$. Does anyone know of any online calculators that can I can use?

Comment: what does it mean, "$\eta^2$ is equivalent to $R^2$" ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I could well be wrong about this, but...I think I would take the square root, yielding eta, which is akin to multiple R.  Then I would use the standard method for finding a confidence interval for a correlation, which involves transforming to a Fisher's *Z*, obtaining upper and lower confidence limits based on *Z* and *N*, and transforming back.  Then I'd square these limits to get my upper and lower limits for eta-squared. (One online calculator that could help is [Vassar's](http://vassarstats.net/tabs.html#fisher).)

Comment: This is really quite a clever solution, +1. I went looking for my meta-analysis book this morning, but I couldn't find it...

Comment: And intuitive too!