# Calculating CIs for $\eta^2$ via Z scores - sample size?

Tags: confidence-interval, effect-size, fisher-transform

In the thread
[Confidence Interval for $\eta^2$](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/28247/confidence-interval-for-eta2?rq=1) it was proposed that if only limited statistics are available (in my case, *F, df1, df2*, means), one could calculate the 95% CI for $\eta^2$ by:

- transforming $\eta^2$, which is equivalent to $R^2$, into *r*
- transforming *r* into a Z score (*artanh*)
- calculating the CI of the Z score (as +/- 1.96*SE)
- back-transforming all values (*tanh*) and squaring them to get to $R^2$/$\eta^2$

  1. Is this general approach sound?
  2. The SE of the Z score is given as $\frac{1}{\sqrt{N-3}}$. What does *N* correspond to here? For example, my $\eta^2$ comes from a repeated-measures ANOVA (one factor, 4 levels). Should I use the total number of samples, the *N*, or *df2*, or ..? And possibly: why?

Answer (score 7):

In case you are still interested in this topic, I would recommend you to take a look at the papers, referenced in [my answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/143882/31372), especially the first one (by Lakens). Also, check MBESS `R` package: see [home page](http://www3.nd.edu/~kkelley/site/MBESS.html) and [JSS paper](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v20/i08/paper) (note that the software's current version most likely contains additional features and improvements, not described in the referenced original JSS paper).

Answer (score 4):

This is an interesting suggestion. It has one limitation: Fisher's z -- which is the name of this approach -- gives results between -1 and 1 but eta's are only positive. In UniMult, I am using Cox and Hinkley's definition of confidence intervals as the range of possible population values from which the observed value is non-significant. Than a simple loop in a computer program is used to test the range of values. With a bit of patience or the help of a web calculator, this could be done for an occasional eta.